# Adding a text to plotly below the legend

Tags: plotly

I would like to add some text to a plotly scatter plot.
I have read about the annotations but these set the text related to specific points of the plot.
What I want to do is to put text *outside* the plot, below the legend.

Something like

[image: plot]

As you can see I would like the text in blue there
The original plot is

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import numpy as np

x = np.arange(-4,5)
y=x**3



# build figure
fig = go.Figure(data=go.Scatter(x=x, y=y,name="something"))
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=x,y=y**2,name="another"))
fig.show()
```

what should I use?

Answer (score 0):

From the [Plotly Documentation](https://plotly.com/python/text-and-annotations/#adding-annotations-with-xref-and-yref-as-paper), it is mentioned that **fig.add_annotation()** can be used to place text anywhere within the figure or outside the figure if you want.

Below is the sample tweaked code for your reference

```py
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objects as go

df = px.data.wind()
fig = px.scatter(df, y="frequency")

fig.update_layout(xaxis=dict(domain=[0, 0.5]), yaxis=dict(domain=[0.25, 0.75]))
fig.add_annotation(
    text="An annotation whose text and arrowhead reference the axes and the data",
    xref="paper", yref="paper",
    x=1.1, y=0.3,
    showarrow=False
)

fig.show()
```